# How do I read 初商業誌?

Tags: kanji, readings, compounds, prefixes

I searched google, jisho, and yahoo. I couldn't find a proper pronunciation for 初商業誌.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's read as はつしょうぎょうし.

You can never find it in dictionaries because it's actually three words:

- 初【はつ】: first ([jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%88%9D))
- 商業誌【しょうぎょうし】: commercial book/magazine (often as opposed to [dōjinshi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%8Djinshi))

  - 商業【しょうぎょう】: commerce ([jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%95%86%E6%A5%AD))
  - 誌【し】: (suffix) magazine ([jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%AA%8C))

初商業誌 is typically used when a dōjin manga-ka makes a debut on a magazine available in the commercial market.

Comment: Doesn't seem obvious whether to use the on-yomi or kun-yomi for 初, especially since the other 3 kanji are all on-yomi. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -2):

Just ask Google translate to detect the language, then hit 'Translate'. Google translate can be pretty sucky from time to time so don't treat it as gospel, but use it as a translation aid:

[https://translate.google.fr/?pli=1#auto/en/初商業誌](https://translate.google.fr/?pli=1#auto/en/%E5%88%9D%E5%95%86%E6%A5%AD%E8%AA%8C)

"The first commercial magazine"